# Check if enum type is ulong

Tags: c#, types

I have an Enum and I want to check if enum type is ulong.

Tried so far:

```
 var checkValue = Enum.GetUnderlyingType(param.ParamType); // param is enum
 if (checkValue is ulong){ } // doesn't work

 var checkValue = param.value;
 if (checkValue is ulong){ } // doesn't work
```

any ideas?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

[`Enum.GetUnderlyingType`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.enum.getunderlyingtype.aspx) returns a object of type `Type` so, it indeed is not an `ulong`, it's the `ulong` type itself :)

Try this:

```
if (checkValue == typeof(ulong))
```

Comment: Sometimes a second pair of eyes is all that is needed :)

Answer (score 0):

Well try this:

```
var enumType = param.GetType();

var utype = Enum.GetUnderlyingType(entype);

if(utype == typeof(ulong))
```